# awk and csv columns

Tags: awk, scripting

I have a csv file that looks like this:

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4d8s.png)

Raw CSV (;-separated) to be parsed:

```
number;abc;gender;middel;name;last name;existfrom;existuntil;ahv;specialnum;UID;pert;address;street;numberstr;po box;place;cntr;cntrcd;from;until;date;extra 
1;100000388;lady;W;jane;doe;16.08.1930;31.12.9999;7.56777E+12;500000387;;N;WOA;angel;47;;6020;moon;NL;16.01.2016;31.12.9999;31.12.9999; 
2;100000453;mister;M;jon;doe;29.12.1934;31.12.9999;7.56663E+12;500000452;;N;WOA;angel;11;;6314;moon;GR;16.01.2016;31.12.9999;22.09.2008;mutation 
3;100000469;lady;W;jane;doe;16.02.1941;31.12.9999;7.56486E+12;500000468;;N;WOA;angel;11;;6314;mooon;DE;16.01.2016;31.12.9999;22.09.2008;mutation 
4;100000490;mister;M;jon;doe;09.05.1936;31.12.9999;7.56841E+12;500000497;;N;WOA;silicon;65;;6340;moon;CZ;16.01.2016;31.12.9999;15.12.2010;Mutation
```

Formatted table for ease of reading:

```
+--------+-----------+--------+--------+------+-----------+------------+------------+-------------+------------+-----+------+---------+---------+-----------+--------+-------+-------+--------+------------+------------+------------+-----------+
| number |    abc    | gender | middel | name | last name | existfrom  | existuntil |     ahv     | specialnum | UID | pert | address | street  | numberstr | po box | place | cntr  | cntrcd |    from    |   until    |    date    |  extra    |
+--------+-----------+--------+--------+------+-----------+------------+------------+-------------+------------+-----+------+---------+---------+-----------+--------+-------+-------+--------+------------+------------+------------+-----------+
|      1 | 100000388 | lady   | W      | jane | doe       | 16.08.1930 | 31.12.9999 | 7.56777E+12 |  500000387 |     | N    | WOA     | angel   |        47 |        |  6020 | moon  | NL     | 16.01.2016 | 31.12.9999 | 31.12.9999 |           |
|      2 | 100000453 | mister | M      | jon  | doe       | 29.12.1934 | 31.12.9999 | 7.56663E+12 |  500000452 |     | N    | WOA     | angel   |        11 |        |  6314 | moon  | GR     | 16.01.2016 | 31.12.9999 | 22.09.2008 | mutation  |
|      3 | 100000469 | lady   | W      | jane | doe       | 16.02.1941 | 31.12.9999 | 7.56486E+12 |  500000468 |     | N    | WOA     | angel   |        11 |        |  6314 | mooon | DE     | 16.01.2016 | 31.12.9999 | 22.09.2008 | mutation  |
|      4 | 100000490 | mister | M      | jon  | doe       | 09.05.1936 | 31.12.9999 | 7.56841E+12 |  500000497 |     | N    | WOA     | silicon |        65 |        |  6340 | moon  | CZ     | 16.01.2016 | 31.12.9999 | 15.12.2010 | Mutation  |
+--------+-----------+--------+--------+------+-----------+------------+------------+-------------+------------+-----+------+---------+---------+-----------+--------+-------+-------+--------+------------+------------+------------+-----------+
```

Among other tasks, I need to get the 3 last digits from column I and place them into column O, but with no success.

for example. 
The column I has a number 7567766885966, I need to get the 966 and put it into column O, replacing the existing number that is in column O.

Until now I have managed to do this:

```
#!/bin/sh 

oldCsvFile=old.csv 
newCsvFile=new.csv 

#insert first line as is to the new file 
head -1 $oldCsvFile > $newCsvFile 

#replace columns 7 and 13 /w overwriting values 
awk '{FS=";"; OFS=FS; $7="\"01.08.2019\""; $13="\"RandomStreet\""; print $0}' $oldCsvFile >> $newCsvFile
```

delete second and last line, which are the first and last line of the original file /w overwritten columns

```
sed -i '2 d' $newCsvFile 
sed -i '$ d' $newCsvFile
```

insert unmodified last line to the new file

```
tail -1 $oldCsvFile >> $newCsvFile'
```

Can you please help me out?

Comment: Welcome to SO, your question is not clear, please do mention samples of input and expected output more clearly in your post and let us know.

Comment: Post your data here cut/past, not a picture.

Comment: @Jonte, I couldn't paste data, only picture as SO said I cannot post data just yet

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, I hope now it is more clear?

Comment: @Panos, You need to wrap your samples in CODE TAGS(see my edit when wrapped your codes in it) then it should allow it.

Comment: @Panos,Please see this post once https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: ... and the data is in exponential notation? For example, first data in column "I" (Excel expected) is 7.56777E+12 and the last three chars is pretty much everytime "000".

Comment: Which column is I and which is O? Neither of those names appear in the header line...

Comment: You can use substr function to extract part of the string, for example:

    $O=substr($I, length($I) -2)

Replace O and I with field numbers.

Comment: @Shawn, I want to get the last 3 numbers from "ahv" and add it to "numberstr", replacing the values that are in "numberstr". I hope this makes it clearer?

Comment: @JamesBrown this is how the numbers appear in excel only. normally, via "less" or "cat" the csv, you get the whole numbers. And they are not 000. I hope this helps a bit.

Comment: awk 'BEGIN{FS=";"; OFS=FS} NR==1 {print;next} {$15=substr($9, length($9) -2);print}' file.csv

Comment: @Panta many thanks for your solution. It does work, but when I try to run it after the 

`awk '{FS=";"; OFS=FS; $7="\"01.08.2019\""; $13="\"RandomStreet\""; print $0}' $oldCsvFile >> $newCsvFile`

I get 2 set of inputs on my output file.
Do you think that I could have both `awk` lines into one?

Comment: @Panta never mind :) I found it!
```awk '{FS=";"; OFS=FS; $7="\"01.08.2019\""; $15=substr($9, length($9) -2); $9=$9*10; $14="\"RandomStreet\""; print $0}' $oldCsvFile >> $newCsvFile```